# How to tell if a chain is Bicycle Chain or something else?

Tags: chain

Hello is there anyone that is able to help me?  I need to get a new chain for my little boy's quad bike and I'm unsure on what size I need to get.

Its a 50cc mini motor quad bike. I have looked online but says all different numbers of links and the one that is on it already is too small as I bought it off some bloke who didn't have a clue what he was doing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  While we do accept questions about vehicles with more than 2 wheels (like trikes), purely motor-driven vehicles aren't on-topic for this forum.  You might try on [mechanics.se] instead.

Comment: You probably need to measure the chain links.  Which can be a little tricky.

Comment: @DavidW concur - but there's still a chance this uses bicycle chain, cos its cheap.  I've tried to answer in that vein.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about motor vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

From a little research it would appear most Mini Moto Bikes & Quads up to 50cc mostly use a 25H or 25E chain. 
They vary in price depending on retailer but most seem quite easy to buy being a popular item. As we know very little else regarding main drive dimensions (cog / gearing) apart from the fact it should only consist of a main drive gear and a smaller one on the rear axle.

All I can do is attach a chart of the most likely chains and the OP can hopefully work out what chain is required according to the dimensions on the gearing.
[image: Most Likely Compatible Chains]

[image: Chain Stamped 25H]

Comment: Yeah I was tempted to start going into all this when writing my answer, but as soon as its not bicycles, then its off-topic for here.  Probably OP should repost this in mechanics.se ?

Answer (score 0):

First up - confirm that its Roller Chain. There's a metal doughnut roller around each pin in this example:

[image]
If it doesn't look pretty close to this, then its not bicycle chain.

Then check if its a bicycle chain.  The pitch **will** be exactly 1 inch / 25.4mm per pair of inner+outer links, with maybe up to 1-2% longer if its worn.   This is the same as saying 0.5 inches between adjacent chain rollers/pins.

Any other chain pitch and you're looking at a motorbike chain.

Then move to measuring the width, between the inner plates.

- 1/8" (0.125", 3.18 mm) chain is used on most single-speed bicycles, and this would be my guess.
- 3/32" (0.094", 2.30 mm) chain is used on deraileur equipped bicycles.

Again if its not one of those two, you have motorbike chain, or possibly something different again.